# Type Clash when using Datediff(...Dateadd(...),Getdate()) in Sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase, getdate

I've switched companies and in doing so, switched from `SQL Server` to `Sybase-ASE`. I can't tell if I'm just having a brain fart and am coding incorrectly or if there is a difference between running `Datediff(...Dateadd(...),Getdate())` in `SQL Server` and `Sybase-ASE`. I'm getting a `type clash (INT)` on the `Datediff` side of the formula when running the code below. Running `Dateadd` by itself works fine. Not sure if something needs to be tweaked or it just can't be done in `Sybase-ASE`. Any help? I checked these other questions but no real help ([Subtract one day from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631977/subtract-one-day-from-datetime) [GETDATE last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114592/getdate-last-month) [Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server) [Datediff GETDATE Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168871/datediff-getdate-add))

```
SELECT TOP 5 *

FROM SalesData fm
WHERE fm.Date = DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,MAX(fm.Date)),GETDATE())
```

ALSO, side question: I can't remember what the specific formula is to get the whole of last month is in `Datediff` if anyone happens to know. I can figure it out I just figured it's best to kill two birds with one stone. It's apparently somewhat difficult to get a `Dates` table implemented into production...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it thanks to this post([Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server?lq=1))

```
where DATEPART(MONTH,fm.Date) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(YEAR,fm.Date) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR,0,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

On the point of built-in functions, ASE and SQLServer are nearly identical. There is however one difference, and this is what you may be hitting. In SQLServer, you can use a numeric value for a date, which is interpreted in SQLServer as #days since 01-01-1900. ASE does not support using numeric values as a date, and you will get a syntax error.